# How to let Status Bar not be part of Safe Area?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, interface-builder, statusbar

My `.plist`'s `UIStatusBarHidden` is `false`, so my app does not show the iOS status bar.

The UI elements that are connected to the top of a custom `UIView` I have, appear too high on iPhone 6/7/8 devices.  This is because IB takes the status bar into account in my top constraints. (The iOS status bar is the Safe Area in my XIB.)

How do I tell IB that I don't have a status bar, so that my top UI elements appear correct for iPhone 6/7/8.  I don't want to mess up they layout for iPhone X devices, which is already okay.

How things look in IB:
[image: IB]

When running on Simulator:
[image: Simulator]

By switching off the Safe Area option, it's possible to get the iPhone 6/7/8 correct (by increasing the constraint constants), but then these UI elements will be too high on iPhone X devices.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can remove safearea at the storyboard options

Storyboard Instpector
[image]

Constraint top to root view
[image]

Comment: After increasing the constants of the top constraints thing will look good for iPhone 6/7/8 devices.  But for iPhone X devices, these UI elements will be too high. So this doesn't work.